# SharePoint Online - potx (powerpoint template files) not returned in search results

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have some Powerpoint template files (*.potx) files in SharePoint online. But search in the site not returing any *.potx files

Answer (score 0):

As per the following article, the filetype *.potx is not included in the  SharePoint Online File Type List and hence potx files are not parsed by the SharePoint search crawler.

- http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.in/2015/03/sharepoint-2013-search-file-extensions.html

Also refer the following article to learn which file name extensions SharePoint 2013 crawls by default and which file types it parses by default.

- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219530(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Yes, I have gone through this article and i could not understand as to what is the reason behind  not allowing potx files to crawled by default. And is there any way i can enable potx files to be crawled? I was able to configure this in my on-premise version of sharepoint 2013 but not in sharepoint online